# Extract enclosure from rss feed into an image

Tags: php, xml

I need to extract the image url from this enclosure. How can i access it?

```
["enclosure"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement) {
    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) {
        ["url"]=> string(81) "http://image.jpg"
        ["length"]=> string(4) "5000"
        ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$url = (string) $var['enclosure']->attributes()->url;
```